# I'm getting errors when I try to create AVD on android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to create a virtual android device but it keeps on telling me "an error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details"
[this is the problem I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2udq1.png)

Also the recommendation below pops up "Please file a bug against android Studio" when  I try to troubleshoot.[This is the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyLTu.png)

Please  I need solution to this problem.